# Mapping Table to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I already have a project in Entity Framework. The Model1.edmx file has several Entities which come from SQL Server Database. I added a new table in SQL Server Database. And I added a new entity in Model.edmx. And when I try to map this new entity with newly added database, that database does not show up in the table mapping. Help Please.

Comment: How did you add a new entity to the edmx file?

Comment: Work model-first *or* database-first, don't mix both modes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manually adding the entity and trying to map them; why dont you try to to use the update from database option when you right click the edmx file. Select your newly created table and the model should regenerate itself with proper associations and relationships.

Comment: Hi Robotsushi, Thanks for the help. I tried that option too. But it gave me more than 100 errors when I had 0 at the beginning. As I am completely new to entity framework, I did not dare to do that.

Comment: hmm.. I would delete your config string and your edmx file. Then re-generate the edmx (which will generate the connection string) and you should be good to go. I've done this before when EF wasn't updating properly and had success.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to map entities manually.

To add an entity and map those follow the steps below -

1. Right click on edmx file and select 'Update model from database'
2. This will open a window where you can choose and add newly added table.

After doing this, expand your .tt file and ensure that .cs file has been auto generated.

If this is not created, right click on every .tt files and select 'Run custom tool' from the options. This will auto-generate required files.